# How can I style a layout in PySide2?

Tags: python, browser, pyside2

I'm trying to create a web browser with `PySide2`, but for some reason, I can't style a layout that is `QHBoxLayout`. Like @musicamante said "Layouts are not widgets, they are layout managers, they do not show as they are not graphics, they do not paint anything, and there is nothing to style". Therefore, I improved my question to be more specific and asked the general public if they had any idea on how I can put a frame inside the `QHBoxLayout`. Or better by simply creating dialog that stretches a certain amount so it looks like a menu.

If you have any better ideas on how I can improve the quality of code, I will gladly accept them. Also, if you think I did anything wrong on my question please let me know in the comments.

```
import os
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtWebEngine import *
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class BrowserEngine(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BrowserEngine, self).__init__()
        self.webview = QWebEngineView(self)
        self.webview.load("https://www.duckduckgo.com")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        self.back = QPushButton("Back", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.webview.back)

        self.reload = QPushButton("Reload", self)
        self.reload.clicked.connect(self.webview.reload)

        self.forward = QPushButton("Foward", self)
        self.forward.clicked.connect(self.webview.forward)

        self.entrypoint = QLineEdit(self)
        self.entrypoint.setMinimumSize(200,20)
        self.entrypoint.setMaximumSize(300,20)
        
        self.navigation = QHBoxLayout() # For some reason I can't style this
        # Is it because it wasn't designed in the first place?
        self.navigation.addWidget(self.back)
        self.navigation.addWidget(self.reload)
        self.navigation.addWidget(self.forward)
        self.navigation.addWidget(self.entrypoint) 
        self.navigation.addStretch() 
        
        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.mainlayout.addLayout(self.navigation)
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.webview)
        self.setLayout(self.mainlayout)

        # To use this, just make a new file called "style.qss" in the same path as the main file
        stylesheet_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'style.qss')
        with open(stylesheet_path, 'r') as file:
            self.setStyleSheet(file.read())

class BrowserWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BrowserWindow, self).__init__()
        self.widget = BrowserEngine()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
    

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    module = BrowserWindow()
    module.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "style a layout"? Layouts are not widgets, they are *layout managers*, they do not "show" as they are not graphics, they do not paint anything, and there is nothing to style.

Comment: In that case, how can I make a navigation/menu bar without layouts? Do I have to use a frame? Or is there another way?  @musicamante

Comment: Your question is unclear. Layouts are almost always necessary (except for widgets that implement them on their own, such as QToolBar), but this has absolutely ***nothing*** to do with visual appearance. Please try to explain better what you're *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I edited so you can understand it better @musicamante

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear what is the problem, and your usage of terms such as "frame" (which normally is a container), "dialog" (which is a top level window) and "menu" (which can have different meanings depending on the context) is a bit confusing. Please try to explain what is the expected behavior, and eventually provide a couple of images showing what you get and what you need.

Comment: In that case, I just want to know how I can make a menu-bar. Such as the ones you see in popular browsers. @musicamante

Comment: Modern browsers do not have a "menu bar", they have a menu button. If you want a "classic" menu bar (like those used in basic and legacy programs), use QMenuBar. Otherwise, what you're looking for is *not* a menu bar, it's a toolbar. As said, I believe you have to clarify some important aspects of terminology. In any case, it's still really unclear what is the problem, and unless you answer to what has been asked using proper details and terminology, we cannot help you in any way.

Comment: My bad for mixing up the toolbar with the menu-bar, I will notice this. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries, nobody's perfect. Becoming aware of lacks in our knowledge is an important step for improving it. Still, if you want help, we need to know what asked above: right now your question is too vague and imprecise, so please put more efforts in explaining what you want to achieve. Remember that most SO users don't speak English as their native language, so you have to try to be as clear as possible. If English is not your mother tongue, then please try to find some friend or colleague that might help you rephrase what you're asking in order to make it understandable to anybody.